# why download apk file is buffered and gives user old version

Tags: azure, download, apk

We hold our landing page on `Azure` and it is for users to download an Android `apk` file. This landing page is a html file. Here is the markup for users to download:

```
<a href="android/[MyAndroidApp].apk" class="...">download here</a>
```

It all works fine until now. Users start to complain that the app they downloaded cannot work properly. But when we tested, it works fine.

Finally we find out that, although the link is

```
http://www.[mysite].com/android/[MyAndroidApp].apk
```

but sometimes when user click it, it goes to

```
http://101.44.1.131/cloud/223.210.55.28/files/9216...636//www.[mysite].com/android/[MyAndroidApp].apk
```

This is a buffer and holds an old version of our app!

Can anyone tell me why this happen and how can I prevent it buffer our old version?

Comment: I suggest you to use Azure Storage instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions.

We have found the reason. Looking at the redirect url, it is actually some ISPs cached our apk files. They are doing this so that they can save themselves money and bandwidth. This is a common practice in some countries and is well documented.

How evil it is.

Our solution is thus change the file name very time we deploy a new version.

Comment: Hi martial, that's the solution I gave. Can you mark it as an answer? So this thread can be found as solved.

Comment: Hi, wuerzelchen, the answer you gave is the solution, however it doesn't specify the cause for this problem which is more critical in this case. I appreciate your answer, but in order not to confuse other developers, I will not mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

How often do you update this apk file?

May be a caching issue, but not sure exactly.

Have you tried using Azure storage? Upload the file on there, and then link directly to it.

Should cost you less in the long run and not cause any buffering/cache issues

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to put version numbers after your filename. This is also a good practice for .js files. A problem is very often that it's cached and the cache not updated correctly. It's a general problem in the web.
So. Try to put version numbers after the file name, and let us know if this works.